# Unable to login thru ssh after upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04.1

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-13.10

Well, I used `do-release-upgrade` and the system upgraded as I've done normally, and some custom key mappings here.

But then I cannot login from ssh

```
login as: root
root@domain.net's password:
Access denied
root@domain.net's password:
Access denied
root@domain.net's password:
```

So what should I login as?

I've use the option `yes` on an option when it asks me to disable SSH password authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned more about ssh today when I'm strolling through the internet.
Found out that using my private key pair works so maybe it's the new method to prevent bruteforce attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Copying your public key file to the remote system will certainly allow a passwordless connection.

I'm guessing, but I expect the reason you can't login as root has nothing to do with ssh setup.

The root user probably does not have a password set, which is the default for many of the Debian derived distributions.  This is done by setting a password entry in the /etc/shadow file to an "impossible" value.

Comment: Looks like I have so much to learn, but the first line in it (root:%string%:16178:0:99999:7:::) aren't changed since my last backup(before upgrade) so i don't think /etc/shadow is affecting the settings. I've noticed only those files in /etc/ssh are significantly changing such as ssh_config

Comment: Forgot to say, this is a VPS and ssh is probably my only way to login so root password is definitely untouched